# Filling Datagrid using Textbox in C# 2005

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I am creating a windows application in VS C# 2005 in which a datagrid and a button and a textbox are there, what i want to create is that when i enter something in textbox and presses the button the textbox text will be put in the datagrid column1 and if i press that button again a new row of that column1 will be created with the given text in the cell. let me show u what i have created yet. Thanks in advance.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why you want to click twice. May be a usability issue? Use two buttons if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simplist example:

Add the following to a Winform:

- A DataGridView with one (unbound) column
- A Button
- A TextBox

Use the following code to your button's Click event:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: it is right but it is just inserting the textbox1 value, not 2nd textbox value, i want to enter both textboxes value at a time when a button is clicked.